# Does save() makes db call in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to save() an entity outside the transaction boundary. From internet articles, i read, it will issue db call immediately. But in my example, if i write flush(), then only it is making db call.

http://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-save-vs-saveorupdate-vs-persist-vs-merge-vs-update-explanation-with-examples

From my examples, i learnt only txn.commit() or flush() makes the db call. Save() doesn't makes db call.

Does save() makes db call?

I am using postgresql db, hibernate 4.3.1 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save() binds the given entity to the session, generates its ID and returns it.

The linked article incorrectly assumes that save() always inserts the entity immediately, but that's wrong. It does it in their particular case because they use an IDENTITY generator, and the only way to generate an ID for an entity with such a generator is to insert a row in the database and get back the ID generated by the database.

If you use a sequence generator, you'll only see a query being executed to get the next sequence value (unless it has a cache of available IDs in memory). If you use a UUID generator, you won't see any query being executed.

Comment: so when would hibernate actually insert the entity in case IDENTITY is not used? Does one have to flush / commit or how does hibernate know it is "time to reach the database"?

Comment: by default flush is done automatically by Hibernate, when necessary. At most before commit, but also before executing queries whose result might depend on the presence of the new entity in the database.